# React native RTL on Android

Tags: java, android, react-native

Trying to get these few steps here so I can support RTL:
[Making an App RTL-ready](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps.html)
I am trying to add these lines to `MainActivity.java` according to the instructions:

```
I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
sharedI18nUtilInstance.setAllowRTL(context, true);
```

[image]

(I am not a native Android developer, but trying to use react native and occasionally accessing the Android source to modify deeper changes - this one won't compile.)

**`First`**, where do they think `context` should be defined? I can't imagine it's any sort of a global..?

**`Second`**, setAllowRTL shows in red... which seems like a compilation error.
Any idea what they meant? am I even defining this in the right place?

My code looks like this:

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;

import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "myApp";
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
        sharedI18nUtilInstance.setAllowRTL(context, true);
        MainApplication.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Context is the activity you're in.  A context in Android is the Activity, Service, or Application that's currently running, or a wrapper around one.  So its not a global but its pretty broadly scoped.  BTW, do not save one in a static or anything that could exist beyond the activity or you may cause a large memory leak.

Comment: Thanks! Just added an image, which shows that 'context' is not scoped. Is onActivityResult, valid for this?

Comment: You're in an Activity class, and all Activites derive from Context.  Pass in this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add this import in MainApplication.java :

```
import android.os.Bundle; // needed for onCreate method
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;
```

and add

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
    sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), true);
}
```

Comment: I get an error - error: cannot find symbol
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                              ^
  symbol:   class Bundle
  location: class MainActivity
1 error

when following your instructions.
(I'm a Java noob...)

Comment: try to add these line in MainActivity instead of MainApplication

Comment: Can you please tell in more details where this should be added? at the end of the file or in side that function. I got error

Comment: it throws an error complaining about `Bundle` like so: `cannot find symbol
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){`

Answer (score 1):

Add this import in MainActivity.java :

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;
```

```
I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), true);
```

add these line in ReactActivityDelegate

```
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
            return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
      @Override
      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
          I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
          sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), true);
                       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
                      }
    };
          }
```

Comment: can't found getApplicationContext() !